# Multiple display in show view of ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I want to write a small blog with Ruby on Rails (5), with category and doctors submitted via form.

But when I submit a doctor it is often shown twice, and I got no idea why.

Here is the source code of my project.

`doctors_controller.rb` file:

```
def create
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @doctor = @category.doctors.create(doctor_params)
    redirect_to category_path(@category)
end

def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @doctor = @category.doctors.find(params[:id])
    @doctor.destroy
    redirect_to category_path(@category)
end

private

def doctor_params   
  params.require(:doctor).permit(:name, :address, :phno)
end
```

`show.html.erb` file:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<center><h1>        
  <%= @category.name %>
</h1>
</center>
<p1><%= render @category.doctors %></p1>

<p2><%= render 'doctors/form' %></p2>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(@category) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', categories_path %>
```

`_doctor.html.erb` file:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>phone number</th>
  </tr>         
  <% @category.doctors.each do |doctor| %>

    <tr>
     <th><%= doctor.name %></th>
     <th><%=doctor.address%></th> 
     <th><%=doctor.phno%></th>
     <th><%= link_to 'Delete doctor', [doctor.category, doctor],method: :delete,data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
     </th>
    </tr
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: post, please,  your views `index` and `_doctor` (if this partial exists)

Comment: posted the _doctor

Comment: check if you have `jquery_ujs` included twice in your html source of the page

Comment: just press `ctrl + U` in the browser

Comment: jquery_ujs is once .. and by pressing ctrl + u nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

@Prabal-Kar, as Igor suggested are you sure you are 'clicking' the button only once? To prevent users doing this you can [disable the button](https://www.formget.com/enable-disable-button-jquery/) after clicking and you should also ensure you have some [unique constraints](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations) on your doctor model.